# Rails 5 - Building a Collection and Routing to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes

**TL:DR**
I am building a game schedule for a sports league. I have a `has_many_through` relationship between teams and schedules and I want to be able to select `All` and see all games for all teams or to click on a team name and show only home and away games for that team.

I am fairly new to Rails and I am trying to figure out how build a collection and then route to it in Rails 5. The application is supposed to display all `Schedules` (read games) for `All` teams and each individual team.

I have set up a `has_many_through` relationship between 3 models which works and is set as follows:

```
# team_schedule.rb
class TeamSchedule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :schedule
end

# schedule.rb
class Schedule < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_schedules
  has_many :teams, through: :team_schedules
end

#team.rb
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_schedules
  has_many :schedules, through: :team_schedules
  has_many :players
end
```

I am seeding all my data, the data objects I am seeding look as follows:

```
# Team Schedule Data
team_schedules = TeamSchedule.create([{
    away_team_id: 2,
    home_team_id: 1,
    schedule_id: 1,
}

# Team Data
teams = Team.create([{
    abr: 'T1',
    team_name: 'Team One',
    venue: 'Team One Home',
    sm_logo: 'this_is_irrelevant',
    lg_logo: 'this_is_irrelevant'
}

# Schedule Data
schedule = Schedule.create([{
    away: 'Team One',
    home: 'Team Two',
    homeLogo: 'this_is_irrelevant',
    awayLogo: 'this_is_irrelevant',
    date: '26/05/2017',
    leagueGame: 'Game 1',
    prettyDate: 'Friday, May 26th, 6:50pm'
}
```

The `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` on the `team_schedules` allows me to call things like `TeamSchedule.last.home_team` and see the details of that team which works great on my `show` method when showing individual games.

My routes are configured as follows:

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :teams, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :stats, only: [:index]
    resources :players, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :schedules, only: [:index, :show]
  end

  resources :stats, only: [:index]
  resources :players, :schedules, only: [:index, :show]

  root 'schedules#index'
end
```

Which gives me the following routes:

```
        Prefix Verb URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
    team_stats GET  /teams/:team_id/stats(.:format)         stats#index
  team_players GET  /teams/:team_id/players(.:format)       players#index
   team_player GET  /teams/:team_id/players/:id(.:format)   players#show
team_schedules GET  /teams/:team_id/schedules(.:format)     schedules#index
 team_schedule GET  /teams/:team_id/schedules/:id(.:format) schedules#show
         teams GET  /teams(.:format)                        teams#index
          team GET  /teams/:id(.:format)                    teams#show
         stats GET  /stats(.:format)                        stats#index
       players GET  /players(.:format)                      players#index
        player GET  /players/:id(.:format)                  players#show
     schedules GET  /schedules(.:format)                    schedules#index
      schedule GET  /schedules/:id(.:format)                schedules#show
          root GET  /                                       schedules#index
```

I figure the route should look like `teams/:team_id/schedules` and ideally I would be able to just perform a single lookup for each `Team` the same way I managed to  do a `Player` lookup. This `Player` matches the `team_id` associated with the `Player` with a `has_many` and `belongs_to` association and displays them on the view which routes to `teams/:team_id/players` and shows the collection.

The `link_to` part of my view for my `Player` lookup is `team_players_path(@teams[0])` so I was hoping I could do something similarly clean and simple for my schedule lookup.

But the problem I have is that the `team_id` could be in either the `home_team_id` or the `away_team_id` column. On my `schedules_controller` I have figured how I can build a collection as follows:

```
# schedules_controller.rb
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @ts = TeamSchedule.where(nil)
    @teams = Team.where(nil)
    @schedules = Schedule.where(nil)
    @team_one = @ts.where(home_team_id: 1).or(@ts.where(away_team_id: 1))
  end

  def show
    @schedule = TeamSchedule.find(params[:id])
    # Lookup Home & Away
    @away = @schedule.away_team
    @home = @schedule.home_team
  end
end
```

But I don't know how to then route to the `team_one` method to only display that `team_one`s games.

I have tried numerous things but after several days of Googling, reading and trying things on my own and getting nowhere,it's time to ask for help.

Thank you!